# Apache 2 conf with conditionnal RequestHeaders

Tags: apache, apache2

Let's say I have this reverse proxy conf with 2 ProxyPass instruction :

```
ProxyPass /webhook1  http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /webhook1 http://localhost:8080
ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8077
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8077
```

Now, I want to set this header :

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix /webhook1/
```

only if /webhook1 has been matched, not in the general case, can you show me the simplest conf to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Apache conf syntax, but I've just found exactly what I was looking for, so here is the tested answer :

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/webhook1.* WEBHOOK1

ProxyPass /webhook1  http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse /webhook1 http://localhost:8080
ProxyPass /  http://localhost:8077
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8077

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix /webhook1/ env=WEBHOOK1
```